# os.chdir to a directory containing spaces/commas in its name

Tags: python, chdir

I faced a trouble. I have several directories then I need to cd to using os.chdir. But I keep getting errors in the next chunk of code:

```
import os
new_folder = 'Zarazogic acid A'
os.chdir(new_folder)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Zarazogic acid A'
```

I tried to escape characters by:

```
new_directory = 'Zarazogic acid A'
new_directory = new_directory.replace(' ', '\ ')
os.chdir(new_directory)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Zarazogi\\acid\\A'
```

Tried to escape with '\' or even '\\' - still get the same error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're starting in the right directory, and that you actually have a folder named `Zarazogic acid A` in that directory?

Comment: On the face of it, the problem is just that in the directory which the process has as its current directory, there is no sub-directory `Zarazogic acid A`.  The function is trying to change to the directory recognizing the spaces in the name; the directory isn't there.  Check whether you're in the directory you think you're in — or use an absolute pathname to the directory.

Comment: @Wondercricket, sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: Try running `print(os.getcwd())` to see if you are in the directory you expect.

Comment: @user3570029 they mean you might not be in the appropriate parent directory. One quick way, check if 'Zarazogic acid A' is in  `os.listdir()`. Or check `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Tbh, tried to emulate in in interpreter, the directory successfully changed as I can see by `os.getcwd())`, I used the directory name with spaces and etc. Why isn't it working in my script?

Comment: What directory are you *running* your script from? Put `print(os.getcwd())` in your script... that should be illuminating. In other words, the working directory is where you run `python /path/to/my_script.py` not where `my_script.py` lives

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga running from `/home/prosvirov/new_pdb`, this folder contains `Zarazogic acid A` as it can be seen from `os.listdir()`

Comment: Did you try printing those things in your script, and running them so that you reproduce the error? If indeed the current working director is  `/home/prosvirov/new_pdb` and 'Zarazogic acid A` directory is printed in `os.listdir()` when you run your script, then that would be interesting... but please try to rule that out definitively - so not just from the interpreter, but exactly how you are running your script.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, changed all the path to absolute and now it's working. Figured out, that I misspelled one of the folder in script like a dumb. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3 code

Here's a simple Python 3 script (`md23.py`) which shows that the directory isn't where you think it is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

new_folder = 'Zarazogic acid A'

print("0:", os.listdir('.'))
os.mkdir(new_folder)
print("1:", os.listdir('.'))
os.chdir(new_folder)
print("2:", os.listdir('.'))
os.chdir('..')
print("3:", os.listdir('.'))
os.rmdir(new_folder)
print("4:", os.listdir('.'))
```

It's not beautiful, but it works with Python 3 — you'd have to change the printing to make it work with Python 2.

When the script is in an otherwise empty directory, the output is:

```
0: ['md23.py']
1: ['md23.py', 'Zarazogic acid A']
2: []
3: ['md23.py', 'Zarazogic acid A']
4: ['md23.py']
```

This shows that the directory could be created, listed, changed to, that the new directory was empty, that it still existed when changing back up a directory level, and that it could be removed.

You should be able to take this, place it beside your current script, and run it, and it should succeed.  If the `Zarazogic acid A` directory already exists, it will fail.  For example, if I create the directory before running the script, I get this output:

```
$ mkdir 'Zarazogic acid A'
$ python3 md23.py
0: ['md23.py', 'Zarazogic acid A']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "md23.py", line 8, in <module>
    os.mkdir(new_folder)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'Zarazogic acid A'
$
```

#### Python 2 code

A variant script, `md29.py`, with directory names printed too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os

new_folder = 'Zarazogic acid A'


print "0:", os.getcwd(), os.listdir('.')
os.mkdir(new_folder)
print "1:", os.getcwd(), os.listdir('.')
os.chdir(new_folder)
print "2:", os.getcwd(), os.listdir('.')
os.chdir('..')
print "3:", os.getcwd(), os.listdir('.')
os.rmdir(new_folder)
print "4:", os.getcwd(), os.listdir('.')
```

Example run:

```
0: /Users/jleffler/soq/junk ['md23.py', 'md29.py']
1: /Users/jleffler/soq/junk ['md23.py', 'md29.py', 'Zarazogic acid A']
2: /Users/jleffler/soq/junk/Zarazogic acid A []
3: /Users/jleffler/soq/junk ['md23.py', 'md29.py', 'Zarazogic acid A']
4: /Users/jleffler/soq/junk ['md23.py', 'md29.py']
```